# Upload file to AWS with Swift trough php

Tags: php, swift, amazon-web-services, upload

i found this swift code and seems to work fine but i don't know how to parse it in php.
I need to send image data and parameters (eg. name = Steve & age = 20) to a php web service that can upload image on AWS S3 storage and do something on my mysql db.

my swift code is:

```
<pre>

       

func upload(fileData:Data, fileName:String , completion: @escaping (_ fileURL:String?, _ error:String?) -> Void) {
        let boundary = "----------V2y2HFg03eptjbaKO0j1"
        let requestUrl = NSURL(string: self.WSurl.dammiUrl(m_path: .uploadCertificatoMedico, query: ""))
        var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
 let fname = "certificatoMedico.jpg"
        let mimetype = "image/png"

        var body = Data()
        body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"nomeDb\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        body.append("\(nomeDb)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

        body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"codFiscale\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        body.append("SCRSFN77C19F205K\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

        body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"\(fname)\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        body.append("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        body.append(fileData)
        body.append("\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

        body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

        request.httpBody = body

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let _:Data = data as Data?, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(nil, error!.localizedDescription)
                }
                return
            }
            if let response = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)) {
                print("- - - - SS96 -> RESPONSE: " + response)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(response, nil)
                }
                // NO response
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(nil, nil)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }



</pre>
```

here how i call this:

```
<pre>
guard let image = self.imageView.image else {
print("imageView.image == nil")
            return
        }

        guard let image_data = image.pngData() else {
            print("UIImagePNGRepresentation returned nil")
            return
        }

        self.upload(fileData: image_data, fileName: "test.jpg") { fileURL, error in
            if error == nil {
                print("url = \(fileURL)")
            }
        }
</pre>
```

can you tell me the best way to get variables and image data to upload on AWS S3 on php?

Comment: you are not using the AWS SDK?

Comment: Nobody can tell you what is the best way.

Comment: I think using the AWS SDK is pretty close to be the best way ;)

Comment: i can't use the AWS SDK because it doesn't work on Action Extension appx